# Asterisk Originate Some noooob Questions ^_^'

Tags: asterisk, asteriskami

its a couple of day I'm working on Asterisk, developing some application to call tracking & monitoring and etc ...(Asterisk.Net lib)

i want to tell my extension(phone) on desk to call some number when i press a button in my application.

well I've done some Googling to get to Originate

```
Action: Originate
ActionID: 1234
Channel: **??***
CallerId: **??**
Context: from-internal
Exten: [targetPhoneNo]
Priority: 1
Async: true
TimeOut: 30000
Variable: logedInUserId:113
```

well i don't know how this gonna work. OTL

1st : where is my extension information (phone on the desk)

cahnnel : is this source channel or destination channel how can i get channel state if one them was busy or whatever ?(e.g DAHDI/101 is busy )

callerId : is it optional can i put whatever i want there ?

context : do i have to set this or asterisk itself gonna process it

..............[EDIT]................
thx for ur answer ^_^

in my case Asterisk worked this way :

when i want to make Internal call SIP to SIP call

SIP registered user 551 wants to call  SIP user 101 :

```
Action: Originate
ActionID: 1234
Channel: SIP/551
CallerId: 101
Context: from-internal
Exten: 101
Priority: 1
Async: true
TimeOut: 30000
```

when i want to make outbound call SIP to Mobile No

SIP registered user 551 wants to call  Mobile 0999-1234-1234 :

```
Action: Originate
ActionID: 1234
Channel: DAHDI/g0/099912341234
CallerId: 099912341234
Context: from-internal
Exten: 551
Priority: 1
Async: true
TimeOut: 30000
```

channel :

```
DAHDI -> its channel Protocol
g0 -> trunk
```

Comment: Question is too broad. Read some book, for example "Asterisk the future of telephony"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your extension is SIP then you have to register with sip client in your asterisk server.

```
SIP SHOW PEERS
```

Will show you which are the current active extensions mapped into your asterisk server

I assume you have your desk phone(PSTN) and number is 9123456.
**Channel** will be

```
Channel : DAHDI/g0/9123456
```

Channel is source channel.

**CallerId** is What you want to show as display number when call is initiated into your phone.

```
CallerId : 91123454
```

You will see call is coming from this number.Yes it is optional. In india you can not put anything(Legal issue). If you are using voip service you can put any number, But again there is legal concern of fraud. You have to own that number.

**context** is where you dial your destination number. You have to write the context in asterisk config file. Suppose

```
context: your_context
```

When you receive the call, It will jump to that context

```
[your_context]
exten => _X.,1,Dial(DAHDI/g0/your_destination_number)
```

In case of SIP replace DAHDI with SIP.and here g0 is the logical PRI group through which you want to dial the number

Comment: brief and very useful ,tvm :>

Comment: @dkakoti How can it then call the customer number from the operator extension? if you say 9123456, it means this is the customer number that the extension 551 will dial?